# System.IntNN, System.UIntNN version requirements

Tags: delphi, compatibility

What's the first version of Delphi that has `Int8`, `Int16`, `Int32`, `UInt8`, `UInt16`, `UInt32` declared in the System unit.

Which `VERnnn` conditional symbol or RTLVersion value do I need to use for detection?

Comment: I think it must have been very, very recent. They really dragged their feet in giving us usable names for those types. If these names were there in Delphi 2007, I never ran across them.

Comment: @David Heffernan, careful, please. That edit was distorting. My primary objective is RTL version #, but "street name" is ok too, since i have table mapping marketing names to versions. "Include" was a call for answering users, because valid response might be too short.

Comment: I've no idea what you are talking about. Street name? The original question just said IntNN which I simply did not understand.

Comment: @user I think your comment about the edit should have been directed at Johan. I only change the IntNN/UIntNN to specific versions.

Comment: @David Heffernan, ah, excuse me, did not notice TWO edits. Your edit was clarifying. "Street names" are coming marketing department and are completely incoherent from the software versioning point of view (eg: Delhi XE, Delphi HUH, Delphi LOLWUT). This trend is best illustrated by usage of `X3` in place of version `13.0`.

Comment: @Johan, please read above and dont do such edits.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand, can you convert your comment to an answer, please?

Comment: @user, the OP was confusing I was trying to clear it up. Please don't post such confusing questions :-).

Comment: @user759588: And so I have done.

Comment: @user Johan is a high rep user, he is perfectly entitled to make such edits. If you wish to revert then that's your right too. This is a wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I know for sure is that these type aliases are declared in Delphi 2009, and I wouldn't be surprised if this is the version in which they first appeared.

Comment: Does someone know for sure that they were introduced in D2007?

Comment: Yeah, as Joe White pointed out D2007 lacks these types, so - D2009. Thank you! (correction: at least on in System unit)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the answer to your question. However, you could avoid needing to know by using code like this in a global include file or a unit that is used by all other units in your code:

```
{$IF Declared(System.Int8)}
{$ELSE}
type
  Int8   = ShortInt;
  Int16  = SmallInt;
  Int32  = Integer;//or Longint if you prefer
  UInt8  = Byte;
  UInt16 = Word;
  UInt32 = Cardinal;//likewise for Longword
{$IFEND}
```

Comment: @David, thanks for this. I hadn't seen `Declared` before, and actually had to copy/paste your code into a project and compile it to believe it worked. :) +1. (BTW, I even added `{$MESSAGE 'Declared worked'}` between the `$IF/$ELSE` to make sure. <g>) That brings up another question, though - when was `Declared` added?

Comment: @Ken White, D6 (check for VER140 or CONDITIONALEXPRESSIONS)

Comment: Feature detection instead of version sniffing, good idea, ought to work too.

Comment: @Ken certainly present in D6, and I have a feeling that's when it was introduced.

Comment: I see a flaw, Cardinal is generic type.

Comment: @user And so is Integer. Use Longint and Longword if you wish. For what it's worth, Integer and Cardinal will be 32 bit even in Delphi 64. The declaration above is the taken straight from System.pas.

Comment: @user, cardinal is an unsigned int32. there's no flaw.

Comment: @Johan, there is, read up on fundamental and generic types. @David Heffernan, i'd edit that, such personal preference might come out as 16bit Int32 :-)

Comment: @user I think we can safely neglect Delphi 1 can't we! Also the $IF won't work.

Comment: @David Heffernan, why not to use correct types and retain portability?

Comment: @user Use Longint and Longword then as I already said. And I say again, the code above comes from System.pas

Comment: @David Heffernan, that mean what System.pas is not portable (and should not be by Borland compiler design). Should we copypaste code from there to our portable code? (as side note: copypasting might violate product license)

Comment: @user, Lazarus/FreePascal uses the same datatypes, what portability issues are you talking about?

Comment: @user Copyright is fine, it's what is known as *fair use*. I don't know what you mean by portable. But this is all pointless. The main idea is `$IF Declared(...)`. What's to stop you putting whatever you like in the definition of `Int32`? I'm not standing in your way.

Comment: @Johan, what's the difference between generic and fundamental type?

Comment: if you can exclude 16 bit then there is no difference, at the moment!

Comment: @user that concept does not exist any more in Delphi. integer is 32 bit. Now and forever. You are talking about c(++).

Comment: @johan I don't think you can say forever. I think the policy is that integer is the same size as a C int on the prevailing platform. That's 32 bits on all known Delphi platforms but it could change in the future.

Comment: @David, @user, from the horse's mouth: "There are two integer types, NativeInt and NativeUInt, whose size will float between 32-bit and 64-bit depending on platform. They've been around for quite a few releases. No other integer types will change size depending on bitness of the target." see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051603/how-should-i-prepare-my-32-bit-delphi-programs-for-an-eventual-64-bit-compiler/4052431#4052431

Comment: @johan that's specifically about upcoming delphi 64 and makes no claims about any other platforms that may be supported in the future

Comment: @Johan, @David Heffernan, you are abusing low diversity of Pascal implementation which leads to monopoly which cannot follow its own rules. Types concept was reeled by gcc vs. MSVC disagreement on 64-bit generic types, reeking havoc in tiny Delphi encampment (remember, Delphi isnt just VisualStudio lookalike, but also MUST maintain compatibility with C++ Builder)

Comment: @David Heffernan, accept my edit then :-P BTW, talking about choosing right types - i have a work-in-progress code which still able to load datafiles created in early 1990