# Delphi 32 to Delphi XE2 (64 bit) conversion

Tags: delphi, 32bit-64bit, delphi-xe, delphi-xe2

I'm looking at migrating a Delphi 2007  business applications to 64 Bit using Delphi XE2.
I wanted to know if there are any guidelines which will help to developers or companies, who are considering migration of there Delphi applications to 64 bit with Delphi XE2.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: migartion -> migration (sorry for the typo)

Answer (score 16):

Here is my advice.

1. First of all port the application to 32 bit Unicode.
2. Then, port to 64 bit.

I would expect step 1 to be harder than step 2. For step 1 there is [Marco Cantù's Unicode whitepaper](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38980). I'm not aware of anything similar yet for 64 bit. I strongly urge you to keep these two porting tasks separate. Smaller independent tasks are always easier than one bigger combined task.

Regarding the 64 bit port I can think of the following issues to deal with:

1. All 3rd party libraries need updating.
2. All inline assembler will need attention.
3. Access to Windows API functions need looking at. A common idion is to pass `Integer(MyObject)`. That needs to be replaced with `NativeInt(MyObject)`.

Other than that I don't think there is much to be concerned about. The Unicode port is likely to be far more problematic.

Barry Kelly's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051603/how-should-i-prepare-my-32-bit-delphi-programs-for-an-eventual-64-bit-compiler#answer-4052431) puts some more flesh on this.

Comment: Both of these goals have a common task, updating third party libraries.  If you have to replace one, of course it makes sense to replace it with one that supports both XE2 Unicode and 64 bit.  Otherwise there is nothing I can add.  Great answer.

Comment: I agree, in fact, porting to unicode involves more work, in my personal experience.

Answer (score 8):

Addtionally to the answer of David you can check the documentation of Embarcadero about this topic

- [Delphi 64-bit compiler Sneak preview (Video)](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/64-bit)
- [`Converting 32-bit Delphi Applications to 64-bit Windows`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Converting_32-bit_Delphi_Applications_to_64-bit_Windows)
- [64-bit Cross-Platform Application Development for Windows](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/64-bit_Cross-Platform_Application_Development_for_Windows)
- [64-bit Windows "Hello World" Cross-Platform Application](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/64-bit_Windows_Hello_World_Application)