# Is it possible to access a TButton using tag?

Tags: delphi

I hope to access a TButton using tag.
IS it possible?

for example, I hope set the caption of a TButton (button1 has tag 3) as 'aaa',
I know I can use

> button1.caption:='aaa';

but I hope to use tag '3' to access the tbutton and set the string value 'aaa'.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Comment: You are going to have be a bit more explicit as to what it is you want to do.

Comment: @user262325 - will you have the tags unique or you want to set the caption for more than one component (have the same Tag for more buttons) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.ChnCaptionByTag(SearchTag: integer; NewCpt: string);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
    if Components[i] is TButton then
    begin
      if TButton(Components[i]).Tag = SearchTag then
         TButton(Components[i]).Caption := NewCpt;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Maaan I always get late. I was giving the same answer. Also tags among the buttons must be unique, otherwise,you have the last button with the spesified tag.

Comment: sorry, taking back, what about Break; from the loop

Comment: @daemon: if user262325 has multiple buttons with the same tag?

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to do

```
 ButtonByTag(3).Caption := 'aaa';
```

You can search through a form's components looking for something with a tag of 3:

```
 var C: TComponent;

 for C in Self.Components do
    if C is TCustomButton then
      if C.Tag = 3 then
        (C as TCustomButton).Caption := 'aaa'
```

But note that you could have plenty of components with the same tag, it's not guaranteed unique.

Comment: Nice - I never knew about the "for C in self.components"; I always did the "for i:=0 to ControlCount (or componentcount)"

Comment: what about Break; from the loop ?

Comment: @M Schenkel - it's since D2005

Comment: @daemon_x: I assume that the OP wants ALL buttons with tag 3.  If he only wants the first one then yes, break is the way to go.

Comment: @Larry Lustig - who knows ? he's probably satisfied with the answer, so this will be maybe the next not accepted solution :(

Comment: @Larry Lustig - +1 for you (for-in)

Comment: @user: Both are answers are pretty much the same, so SimaWBs should take precedence.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
procedure TForm1.SetCaption(iTag: Integer; mCaption: String);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i:= 0 to controlcount-1 do
    if controls[i] is TButton then
      if TButton(controls[i]).Tag = iTag then
        TButton(controls[i]).Caption := mCaption;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetCaption(3,'aaa');
end;
```

Comment: what about Break; from the loop ?

Comment: The original question didn't specify whether multiple buttons might share the same tag... An early _break_ might be wrong.

Comment: +1 for you argument. I wanted also some points, because of the ads reduction :P

Comment: to be a stickler, you can give to the parameters "const" type :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, right now the Tag property is the same size as a Pointer, so you *could*, but you need to describe a bit more of what it is you'd like to do.

I'm not positive that this is going to continue to be the case moving into 64-bit Delphi, but I think that's the case too.

Edit: Yes, `TComponent.Tag` should be a `NativeInt` in future versions.  References: [Barry Kelly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568685/how-to-also-prepare-for-64-bits-when-migrating-to-delphi-2010-and-unicode/4052518#4052518), [Alexandru Ciobanu](http://alex.ciobanu.org/?p=52)

Comment: In a conference in Brazil this year, David I. said that next year there will be a 64 bit and MAC compiler -- The Tag property will be a 64 big integer if code is compiled for 64 bit platform.

Comment: mac compiler？ is it for apple's mac?

Comment: @user262325 - Yes, there's plans to make a Mac compiler for Delphi.  See the [Roadmap](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39934)

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm1.ChangeCaptionByTag(const SearchTag: integer; const NewCaption: string);
var i: Integer;
begin
  for i in Components do
    if Components[i] is TButton then
      if (Components[i] as TButton).Tag = SearchTag then
        begin
          (Components[i] as TButton).Caption := NewCaption;
          Break;
        end;
end;
```