# Make already developed application 64 bit enable

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, delphi-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to also prepare for 64-bits when migrating to Delphi 2010 and Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568685/how-to-also-prepare-for-64-bits-when-migrating-to-delphi-2010-and-unicode)

I have already developed an application in Delphi 7. Now I need to enable it to support 64 bit.

Comment: Are you sure you're asking for 64-bit compiler ? It's not released yet at this time. If you want to know if your application will work on 64-bit Windows be sure it will :)

Comment: @daemon_x: You mean to say all the executables build with Delphi 7 will run on 64 bit OS without any errors. have i interpreted correctly?

Also if i want to make changes in the code to include features or WIN APIs for 64 bit OS then what will be the impact?

Comment: to your first question: `yes; all the executables build with Delphi 7 will run on 64-bit OS without any errors.` And to your second question: `none of the released versions of Delphi have 64-bit compiler yet so we can't enjoy full performance of 64-bit OS. I'm saying enjoy performance because from my point of view there will be more performance than new features.`

Comment: once you will buy a new version of Delphi with 64-bit compiler you'll need to be ready [for this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051603/how-should-i-prepare-my-32-bit-delphi-programs-for-an-eventual-64-bit-compiler/4052431#4052431). And as David mentioned there will be much more work to port your source code from AnsiString to Unicode than to prepare it for 64-bit compiler.

Comment: This may be a duplicate, but it's not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568685/how-to-also-prepare-for-64-bits-when-migrating-to-delphi-2010-and-unicode That asks how to prepare for the upcoming 64 bit release. This question asks how to enable 64 bit support for a Delphi 7 app and clearly OP isn't aware of the release plans for dcc64.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Delphi 7, and indeed all released Delphi Win32 versions, only produce 32 bit executables. However, 32 bit executables run perfectly well on 64 bit operating systems through the WOW64 emulator.  Although this is an emulator, a word that usually implies degraded performance, WOW64 performance is not readily distinguishable from native 64 bit performance.

If you wish to port your Delphi app to 64 bit you need to wait for the next version of Delphi to be released which will produce 64 bit executables.

Then you will have to port your app from Delphi 7 to the latest version of Delphi. This will be a big job because you will also have to port from ANSI string code to Unicode string code. In my view this part of the port will be more time consuming than the 32 to 64 bit part and if you wanted to get a head start you would be wise to start the Unicode port now by upgrading to Delphi XE.

Comment: The next release of Delphi will support both 32 and 64 bit targets, and will be released in three-four months, AFAIK. Thereby there's IMHO no need to upgrade to XE - one would need to upgrade twice in a few months or buy SA. Wait for the next version, then start by porting to unicode first as a 32 bit target, then port to 64 bit - just don't attempt both porting at once, it could be too risky.

Comment: @Idsandon I agree with all that. I'm just saying that if you are doing this to a deadline then your could start now with port no. 1, the one to Unicode.

Comment: Just to enhance your mentioning of 32bit vs 64bit performance. 32bit runs at speed on 64bit due to the processor still being a native 32bit processor. The only true 64bit processor on the Intel line is the Itanium (IA64). Mainstream 64bit (x86-64) is a 32bit CPU with 64bit extensions (mainly regarding things like memory).

Comment: can anyone give me some more information on the performance degradation issues for precompiled Delphi 7 application/executable?

Comment: @Nilesh There are none. A Delphi 7 app will run on a 64 bit OS at just the same speed as on a 32 bit OS installed on the same machine.

Comment: @David: and what about memory consumption and allocation?

Comment: @Nilesh Not an issue. If anything apps run ever so slightly better on 64 bit OS because the underlying OS can take advantage of more advanced processor features, but the reality is that you simply won't notice any difference.

Answer (score 4):

You can check this [official Embarcadero video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pURHj1qKK_Y) which covers the subject.