# Migration from 32 bit [Delphi 7] to 64 bit

Tags: delphi, migration, delphi-7, 32bit-64bit

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to also prepare for 64-bits when migrating to Delphi 2010 and Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568685/how-to-also-prepare-for-64-bits-when-migrating-to-delphi-2010-and-unicode)
>   [How should I prepare my 32-bit Delphi programs for an eventual 64-bit compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051603/how-should-i-prepare-my-32-bit-delphi-programs-for-an-eventual-64-bit-compiler)

I would like to know the approach for migrating from 32 bit [Delphi 7] to 64 bit. What all things i should remember and what all steps i should follow?

What all complexity i might face?

please provide me step by step migration process. What things i should address first?

There are 2 possibilities
1. Using yet to launch Delphi 64 bit version
2. Updating existing code and functionality to use 64 bit OS features

Comment: This question might sound stupid but still Why everybody is worried about 64 bit OS and 64 bit Delphi Compiler? I am very keen to know all the possible issues.

Comment: just to be clear, your option 2 is not possible because you would need 64 bit compiler!

Answer (score 0):

There is no 64-Bit Delphi-Compiler at this time. So you can not do it now, you have to wait until the next Delphi-Version. For the next Delphi a 64-Bit compiler is announced. You can not "use" 64-Bit-OS-Features (What are they? What do you mean exactly?) with 32-Bit compiler. A 32-Bit-application will allways run in the WOW3264-Emulator (on a 64-Bit Windows, of course).

Comment: Nevertheless, this question provides a pretty detailed view of things you can do NOW:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051603/how-should-i-prepare-my-32-bit-delphi-programs-for-an-eventual-64-bit-compiler

Answer (score 0):

> What all complexity i might face?

As stated by Andreas, there's no yet 64-bit Delphi compiler ATM. You can use FPC for now, and regarding the complexities, [Lazarus/FPC wiki](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Multiplatform_Programming_Guide) has addressed them.